# Rails: Update view multiple times in 1 action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am working on a Ruby on Rails (5.2) project. I'm going to be a bit vague on the specifics, as i'm looking for more of a theoretical answer, or suggestion on how to approach this issue rather than a specific solution. In this project I have a button that will initiate a controller action. There is also a field in this same view that displays a 'status' that I want to modify.

Ideally, once the button is clicked, the controller action below is called. ( Assume that the code executed takes time (~10 secs) and cannot be placed in a background job. ) At different points in the functions execution I want to modify a DOM element in the view.

```rb
class x_Controller < ApplicationController
    def function_x
        ...
        # execute some code
        ...
        ( call JS function here w/ msg = 'step 1')
        ...
        # execute some code
        ...
        ( call JS function here w/ msg = 'step 2')
        ...
        # execute some code
        ...
        ( call JS function here w/ msg = 'step 3')
    end
end
```

The JS function that I want to call just modifies a DOM element.

```
function start_loading_bar(msg) {
  $('.progress-message').text(msg + "...")
  $('#progress').fadeIn()
}
```

From the user's perspective, once the button is clicked, a status bar will pop up at the bottom. At different points of the execution, the message that the status bar displays will change from 'step 1' to 'step 2' to 'step 3' without any additional input from the user.

I have tried multiple approaches to this problem.

Initially I just bound the function to an onclick of the button, however, this method doesnt allow me to modify it after, since the onclick is just triggered once at the start.

Next I tried making a partial that holds the DOM element I want to modify and rendering it with different parameters in the controller action. However you cant have multiple redirect_to / render in a single action and I encountered an error.

I want to know if this is at all possible to do? am I approaching this problem correctly? am I overlooking a better implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Action Cable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html). It allows you to broadcast function execution status to the user. And put mentioned function into background job (it allows you to send messages).

Also, when going to production consider using [AnyCable](https://github.com/anycable/anycable) instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try to render flash messages(although I'm not really sure it will work).

Usually this is done via websockets or ajax.
With websockets you would have an openconnection where you would send events from the be and listen to them from the fe. As MrSnax said, you could use actioncable, This is the best approach, but it is a little more complicated and harder to set up.

The second approach would be with pooling. Make ajax request every 1,2,3...n seconds, what you find fit for your usecase and call a your js when you receive something different from the server.